# Вопрос касательно работы ООП в PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
new a();
Class a
{
    final public __construct()
    {
        self::init();
    }
    final static function init()
    {
        print b::init();
    }
}
Class b
{
    final static function init()
    {
        return c::init();
    }
}
Class c
{
    private static $hello='Hello World';
    final static public function init()
    {
        return self::$hello;
    }
}
```

Вопрос
Здраствуйте, есть вопросы по поводу видимости и логики ООП

1. Почему я могу вызвать экземляр класса А если он еще не обьявлен.
2. Знаю что конструктор срабатывает сразу при создании нового класса. Хорошо. Но почему он может вызвать метод init() если он еще не реализован (за constructor)
3. Как я понял в ООП нету области видимости и можно в реализации обьекта вызывать другой обьект, как это работает? 
   Есть ли какие нибудь книги в которых описано все это?

Comment: Вопрос первый ошибочный

Comment: **1.** Сперва компиляция, а потом - интерполяция. Это и к процедурному стилю относится _(например можно над описанием функции прописать её вызов)_ **2.** См. п.1. **3.** Ошибаетесь - в ООП "продвинутая" область видимости. Почитайте `Мэтт Зандстра PHP: объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования.`